# Report from Dashboard of Facebook Page Rate Limit is weird

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a app which call the list Conversations each 10 seconds. If the updated_time is "new", i will access the list Messages. I often reach the Page Limit. But i do not know why the chart is showed as in the image (from 61% to 181% in 1 minute...).

[Image of PageRateLimit report from Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJynV.jpg)

P/S:
I know about the webhook, but because we want to release this version soon, we will make the webhook server later. We just want to handle to make it do not reach the limit. But look like there is no accurate number to calculate it :(

Comment: You can not really calculate this, when there is more than one app that performs actions on the page. Granted, if the other app was yours as well, you could perhaps keep track of your calls you make in both ... but that is likely still not going to be very accurate. So probably be the best thing you can do right now, is watch out for the response headers that will start to appear when you are close to reaching the limit (or already above it), and then make your app pause for a while. (And hitting the API in 10 second intervals was rather a dumb thing to begin with ...)

Comment: The algorithm from Dashboard and the algorithm used for API are different. I checked it in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/, many report about this problem...Thanks for your replying.